# Rails - Authorization with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

I'm trying to learn authorization in Rails.
I'd like to restrict the access to Deals when current_user's bank doesn't participate to it.

Below are my models :

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :bank
    end

class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participating_banks, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :pools, through: :participating_banks
    has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end
    class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :pools
    end
    class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :deal
        has_many :participating_banks, dependent: :destroy
        has_many :banks, through: :participating_banks
    end
    class ParticipatingBank < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :pool
      belongs_to :bank
    end
```

In my application controller, i'd like to create an authorization feature that tells : "UNLESS the deal has, at least, one pool where the current_user.bank has been added, redirect_to root_path".
Then, i'll call it from my other controllers.

Here is what i tried in my Deals Controller, but it doesn't work :

```
def is_user_bank_participating?
        unless @pools.participating_banks.bank_ids.include? current_user.bank
            redirect_to root_path
    end
    end
```

Any idea?

Many thanks?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. How can i avoid users to access to deals where their banks isn't participating?

Comment: no, I just have to clarify if you have already tried and failed

Comment: Actually i tried lots of different ways, but i'm missing something :(

Comment: what happened when you've tried this?

Comment: Here in the error message : NoMethodError in DealsController#show           undefined method `participating_banks' for #<Pool::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fff097e4608>

Comment: Its because you are calling `participating_banks` on a collection of pools - not a single pool.

Comment: yes, and to apply the `participating_banks` to all the pools, you should create additional scope for a bank/deal

Comment: `Pool.joins(:banks).where(banks: { id: current_user.bank }).any?`

Comment: Working :) many thanks :)